# iconv cannot replace Ø

Tags: character-encoding

It appears that `iconv` cannot, for example, replace the letter `Ø`. It was also noted in the second answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php

I have two questions:

1. Can I make `iconv` tell me which diacritics it did not convert?
2. Is there a list of diacritics, `iconv` doesn't support?

Comment: What do you mean? `echo 'éèôØ' | iconv -t ascii//translit` outputs `eeoOE` as expected.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I am converting to `us-ascii`. I will check it out whether `ascii` is a better transliteration target.

Comment: `us-ascii` is the same, but you may need a more recent C library (under GNU/Linux, GNU libc 2.19, not eglibc).

Comment: Really? `echo 'éèôØ' | iconv -t ascii//translit` outputs `eeoOE` but `echo 'éèôØ' | iconv -t us-ascii//translit` gives me `eeo?`. Not for you?

Comment: Whether I use `ascii//translit` or `us-ascii//translit`, I get the same output: `eeoOE` with GNU libc 2.19 (Debian/testing 8.0), `eeo?` on older machines.

Comment: Now how can I update my C library? I thought, my Ubuntu updates automatically on a daily basis?!

Comment: Daily updates are only security updates (or similar). But Ubuntu Utopic (14.10) should have a recent enough glibc (not tried, though).